# Filtering table using sum value from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Working with PostgreSQL, I am trying to filter data from a table using data from another one. This is an example:

Table 1:

```
  id|app|area_app
   1| A |   4.7
   2| A |   4.7
   3| A |   4.7
```

Table 2:

```
  id|spart|area_spart
   1| 1a  |   1.2
   1| 1b  |   1.8
   2| 2a  |   2.1
   2| 2b  |   2.3
   3| 3a  |   0.6
```

I would like to filter the second table selecting the rows (with the same id of the first table) whose sum of `area_spart` is equal to `area_app` of the first table; in this example the resulting table should be:

```
 id|spart|area_spart
  1| 1b  |   1.8
  2| 2b  |   2.3
  3| 3a  |   0.6
```

Total area_spart = area_APP = 4.7

Thanks for all!

Comment: Table 1 `id` exists in Table 2??? Where???

Comment: Yes, is the first column of Table2

Comment: Did you check my (@user2727841) answer???

Comment: Please double check your desired output - it does not make sense as none of the values add up to 4.7 (grouping by id). For ex: id=1 sum(area_spart) = (1.2+1.8)=3.0 yet it is included in your final output. How come?

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN` if you are getting duplicate record from table use this query

```
SELECT table1.id,table2.spart,SUM(table2.area_spart) AS area_spart FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id) GROUP BY table1.id
```

If your are getting the id based record use this one

```
SELECT table1.id,table2.spart,SUM(table2.area_spart) AS area_spart FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id) WHERE table1.id = 'your_id'
```

if your record is not based on id and want to get only one record try this one with `LIMIT`

```
SELECT table1.id,table2.spart,SUM(table2.area_spart) AS area_spart FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id) LIMIT 1
```